# Load from Image from XML to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to load an image from an XML file tag `<image>` to the `ImageView`.

The layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/projectImage" />

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/jobtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="jobtitle">
        </TextView>

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/jobinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:text="jobinfo"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the mainActivity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

At this point i look up if the file already exists, if not, then download and parse it.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "Arbeitsauftrag_Bootsbau_Meier_vom_20150216.kx_job");
            if (file.exists()) {

                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(readFromFile("Arbeitsauftrag_Bootsbau_Meier_vom_20150216.kx_job"));

                NodeList nodeListProject = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PROJECT);
                NodeList nodeListTasks = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TASK);

                //Schleife für Aufgaben
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeListTasks.getLength(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    Element e = (Element) nodeListTasks.item(i);

                    map.put(KEY_UUID_OBJ, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID_OBJ));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_INFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_INFO));
                    map.put(KEY_OBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT));
                    map.put(KEY_LOCATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOCATION));
                    map.put(KEY_OBJECT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_OBJECT_SNR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT_SNR));
                    map.put(KEY_REGISTRATION_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_REGISTRATION_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASKIMAGE));
                    map.put(KEY_TASK_HEADLINE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_HEADLINE));
                    map.put(KEY_TASK_SUBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_SUBJECT));
                    map.put(KEY_TASK_ACTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_ACTION));
                    map.put(KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR));
                    map.put(KEY_TASK_STATUS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_STATUS));
                    map.put(KEY_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e,KEY_TASKIMAGE));

                    taskItems.add(map);
                }

                // Schleife für Auftragsinfos
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeListProject.getLength(); i++) {

                    // Neue HashMap erstellen
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    Element e = (Element) nodeListProject.item(i);

                    // Jedes Kind-Knoten zur HashMap
                    map.put(KEY_UUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID));
                    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                    map.put(KEY_JOBTITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBTITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_JOBINFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBINFO));


                    //Hashmap zur ArrayList hinzufügen
                    projectItems.add(map);
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, projectItems,
                        R.layout.list_item_projects,
                        new String[]{KEY_JOBTITLE, KEY_JOBINFO},
                        new int[]{R.id.jobtitle, R.id.jobinfo});

                setListAdapter(adapter);
                //file.delete();


            } else {
                DownloadXMLFiles dlxmlf = new DownloadXMLFiles();
                dlxmlf.execute();
            }
```

This method is for decoding the base64 string:

```
 public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
```

My `ImageView` is not at the `MainActivity`.

I'm looking how i can put the image from `Base64` to `Bitmap` and set it as Image on my `ImageView`?

P.S. my `ImageView` isn't in the same Layout as my `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create following method to convert from encoded Base64 string to Bitmap

```
Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0,
                    decodedByte.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now use it as follows-

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = decodeBase64(strEncodedBitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

Comment: i can't use imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap) because my ImageView is on other Layout as my contentView

Comment: Can u post some more code, where is your ImageView?

Comment: i have 2 layouts...the mainActivity and the list_item_projects... in my ListViewActivity i have set the content:        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); I think i have to put the image in the adapter but i don't know how...

Comment: If you want to use imageView in ListView, then u should create one activity and one custom adapter. You can set image in imageView in getView() method of custom adapter. Its so easy to create.

Comment: You can learn from this link- http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

If you hv confusion then u can ask me

Comment: This link is also useful, it gives a simple example-
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/